# Cgo. Не получается "обернуть" функцию из bass.dll

Tags: c, golang

Приветствую.

Я работаю над привязкой [bass.dll](http://www.un4seen.com/) в Golang.

Полный код в репозитарии https://github.com/lexesv/gobass.dll

И возникли некоторые трудности. Мне не удается "обернуть" эти функции:

```
typedef BOOL (CALLBACK RECORDPROC)(HRECORD handle, const void *buffer, DWORD length, void *user);
HRECORD BASSDEF(BASS_RecordStart)(DWORD freq, DWORD chans, DWORD flags, RECORDPROC *proc, void *user);
```

Пробовал так:

```
func RecordStart(freq int, chans int, flags int, proc RecordCallback) (int, error) {
        h := C.BASS_RecordStart(C.DWORD(freq), C.DWORD(chans), C.DWORD(flags), (*C.RECORDPROC)(unsafe.Pointer(&proc)), nil)
        if h != 0 {
            return int(h), nil
        } else {
        return 0, errMsg(int(C.BASS_ErrorGetCode()))
        }
    }

type RecordCallback = func(handle C.HRECORD, buffer *C.char, length C.DWORD, user *C.char) bool
```

Но во время компиляции примера происходит ошибка:

cannot use MyRecordCallback (type func(C.HRECORD, *C.char, C.DWORD, *C.char) bool) as type func(bass.C.HRECORD, *bass.C.char, bass.C.DWORD, *bass.C.char) bool in argument to bass.RecordStart

Пример:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(bass.RecordInit(-1))
    fmt.Println(bass.RecordStart(44100, 2, 0, MyRecordCallback))
    select {}
 }
func MyRecordCallback(handle C.HRECORD, buffer *C.char, length C.DWORD, user *C.char) bool {
    fmt.Println("...")
    return true
}
```

В общем, нужна помощь в привязке callback функции RECORDPROC для её последующего использования в Go коде.